# Android/Java Class cast exception.Converting a string to byte array

Tags: java, exception

```
 String item="stringItem";
```

Need to convert this string item to an byte array

```
 byte[] byteItemArray = stringItem.getByte();
```

This throws a class cast exception.
Should i use type casting?

Comment: which line is the exception?

Comment: You can't cast an object to an array of bytes.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Post your `getValue` method please

Answer (score 2):

try `byte [] val= ((String) getValue(key)).getBytes();`

Answer (score 1):

From this I suspect that this line is causing the class cast exception

```
(byte[]) getValue(key);
```

What does getValue() return. If it does not return an object that is byte[] you will get the exception.

Comment: It throws an exception "String cannnot be cast as byte[]"

Comment: if i change this line as `String val=(String)getValue(key);`   then it doesnot throw an exception but the bitmap is not generated

Comment: what is the signature of getValue(). There is not enough information to help. Please update the question

Comment: but what does getValue() do. It sounds like it is returning a String as you do not get the exception. Is getValue() the correct method call?

Comment: public Object getValue(String key)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(byte[]) getValue(key).getBytes();
```